# Extracting data from xml with Python 3

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I am trying to extract figures from a series of xml data.

The xml data looks like:

```
<commentinfo>
  <note>This file contains the sample data for testing</note>
    <comments>
    <comment>
      <name>Romina</name>
      <count>97</count>
</comment>
```

And so on with a new name and comment.

My code is:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'

uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
# print(data)

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
# print('Name:',tree.find('count').text)
lst = tree.findall('comments/comment/count')
# print(len(lst))
# print(lst)
# x1 = result[1].find('comment')

# for item in lst:
#     print('Count', item.find('count').text)

counts = tree.findall('.//count')
print(counts)
```

When I print `counts` I get a longer version of:

```
<Element 'count' at 0x000000000A09FB88>, <Element 'count' at 0x000000000A09FC78>, <Element 'count' at 0x000000000A09FD68>, <Element 'count' at 0x000000000A09FE58>, <Element 'count' at 0x000000000A09FF48>, <Element 'count' at 0x000000000A0A3098>]
```

I am quite new to this, so I don't understand why I am getting these hex numbers, nor do I know how to extract the actual figures.

I am hoping someone can help.

Comment: does `counts.text` satisfy your requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loop through the list and print the text of each element.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'

uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

lst = tree.findall('comments/comment/count')

counts = tree.findall('.//count')

for each in counts:
    print(each.text)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request

url= "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data=html.read()
#print(data)
tags=ET.fromstring(data)
lst=tags.findall('comments/comment')
x=0
for item in last:
  element=int((item.find('count').text))
  x=element+x
print(x)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 0):

This was kind of tricky cause you need to start over the sample suggestion just confuses you even more.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ssl


url=input('Enter location:')
print('Retrieving...',url)
accumulative=0
XML=urlopen(url).read() #readu url
print('Retreived:',str(len(XML)),'characters')
tree= ET.fromstring(XML)
print(tree)
counts=tree.findall('.//count')
print('Count', str(len(counts)))
list=list()
x=None
for i in counts:
    #option 1 accumulation
    accumulative=accumulative+int(i.text)
    x=int(i.text)
    #option 2 list sum
    list.append(x)

print(accumulative)
print(sum(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no suggestion for a pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1887362.xml"
df = pd.read_xml(url, xpath='.//comment')
print(df)

total = df['count'].sum()
print("Count of names:", len(df.index), "Total:", total)
```

Output:

```
         name  count
0      Keziah     96
1     Raghida     94
2       Amira     91
3       Bowen     90
etc.

48     Morgan      6
49     Carter      5
Count of names: 50 Total: 2536
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I was having the same issue. You have to convert the byte data into some sort of str or int. So after I add everything into a list I have my loop run through and read the "text" data and turn it into an int to get the sum.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

# Requests the Website XML is being extracted from
url = input("Enter the URL you're trying to parse:")
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
xml = html.decode()
library = []


# Print URL that XML is being extracted from
print('Retrieving', url)


# Data from the website
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
counts = tree.findall('.//count')

#Adding counts
for number in counts:
    library.append(number)

total = 0
for item in library:
    try:
        count = int(item.text)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    total += count

# Print Results
print('Retrieved', len(xml), 'characters')
print('Count:', len(counts))
print('Sum',total)

Worked for me.
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a slight modification which sums up the count.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
total= 0

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

lst = tree.findall('comments/comment/count')

counts = tree.findall('.//count')

total = 0

for count in counts:
    total += int(count.text)

print('total: ', total)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it addresses the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Noticed that, edited it to include sum = 0, it should work now. Thanks for informing

Comment: Still, using `sum` as a name of a variable is a bad idea.

Comment: If possible, can you please correct it because I'm getting the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

The sample is so confusing, I took some time going through the solutions all of you had and found my own solution. I just want to thank you all for helping me. I hope the next person finding this difficult can find my solution as helpful as the others.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ssl
cnt = None

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1887362.xml'
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
all = tree.findall('.//count')
for cnts in all:
    if cnt is None:
        cnt = int(cnts.text)
        continue
    else: 
        cnt = cnt + int(cnts.text)          
print(cnt)
```